# java connectivity with mysql

Tags: java, jdbc

How to set up type 1 connectivity with MySql datasource and java application in windows xp service  pack 3 environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type I?  Why not Type IV, the 100% Java solution using the JDBC driver?  [This MySQL forum response](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,353620,353714) agrees with me - it's not the right way to go.

I'd [recommend](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) sticking with Type IV JDBC connector.